# Sinter: save detection counts

Tags: stim, sinter

Is there a way to extract all detection events (for each detector individually) that occur during a `sinter.Task`/`sinter.collect` simulation, in a similar way to the output of Stim's `circuit.compile_detector_sampler().sample` function? By default, it only appears to show the count of logical errors instead of all detection events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sinter v1.12, you can pass `count_detection_events=True` to [`sinter.collect`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.collect). On the command line you can pass the flag `--count_detection_events` to [`sinter collect`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_command_line.md#collect).

These arguments add two keys to the `custom_counts` field of the `sinter.TaskStats` object (or column of the CSV file). The keys are `"detectors_checked"` and `"detection_events"`.

Beware that it's not safe to merge data that counted detection events with data that did not count detection events. Also note there's currently no way to ask for *specific* detection events to be counted, e.g. from a desired subset of detectors.